Set multiple schemas to search for a single refPath field in populating query, mongodb nestjs
I have a field name reportedItem with type Types.ObjectId in one of my Nest.JS SCHEMA. It makes the relation with the mongoose id that is provided of any collection to this field..
For example
I have three collections Users , Posts , Comments.
When I provide a User id, in reportedItem field, a relation is created dynamically by mongoose,with that user document from Users collection.
When I provide a post id, in reportedItem field, a relation is created dynamically by mongoose,with that post document from Posts collection.
When I provide a comment id, in reportedItem field, a relation is created dynamically by mongoose,with that comment document from Comments collection.
BUT THE ISSUE ARISES WHEN I TRY POPULATING reportedItem, AS I CAN ONLY PASS ONE SCHEMA TO populate() for single path object
await this.model.find().populate([
  {
    path:'reportedItem',
    model:User.name
   }
]);

SO IF THE OBJECT ID IS OF A USER, THEN THAT DOCUMENT IS POPULATED,AS THE USER.NAME IS PROVIDED AS COLLECTION TO SEARCH, BUT IF THE ID IS NOT OF A USER, THEN IT DOES NOT POPULATE THAT ID DOCUMENT.
IS THERE A WAY SO I CAN SET THE POPULATION TO SEARCH IN MULTIPLE COLLECTIONS?
Something LIKE:
{
    path:'reportedItem',
    model:[User.name,POST.name,Comment.name]
   }

OR ANY OTHER WAY?

Take a look at the example in the docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-refpath - basically in the schema you add a field to the document to tell Mongoose which model should be used, and populate just using the fieldname

I had already checked that. But that does not resolve my issue. As that approach is not dynamic at run time. By that approach , all the fields has to be called in a different db call one at a time. But that is not the case I want. I want just one call to db, and check the provided collections list one by one, in whichever the document is found,bring and populate that.

In that demo it calls await Comment.find().populate('doc') to populate the doc field from 2 different models in a single call.  Is that not what you are trying to do?

What I'm observing is that, in the demo I have to pass the docModel in my schema as a field..Even if I add a field as docModel or something else, the main issue is, you can not simply do populate('field'), you have to do it like this populate( [ { path : 'ref/refPath' , model: 'YourModelToSearch'} ]. In the latest updates, I don't know if it is related to nest or mongoose, the populate method does not work without passing a model with path. Without that you face error MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model, which is a mongoose error.

For the field you want to populate, the model must be registered in one of: ref, refPath, or the populate call.  To avoid needing to pass it in populate, set refPath to a field in the document, and have that field contain the model name you want to populate from.  If you can provide a MSCVE of what you have so far, we can show you how to do that.

I think I got what that demo is trying to show with enum values in dockModel, and by setting the key dockModel as a value for doc key.But I still face error Schema hasn't been registered for model, if even I set refPath instead of ref.

Sorry I don't know the meaning of MSCVE....

Sorry, that was a typo, I meant MCVE - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/2282634

I have to post the code on github?

Actually, this is trivial, I'll demonstrate in an answer

Ok,answer it and I'll test that

To automatically populate a field from multiple models, you need to specify either a field via refPath or a function via ref in the parent schema.
In this example there are 3 possible child schemas:
const PostModel = mongoose.model("Post", new mongoose.Schema({ title:String}));
const CommentModel = mongoose.model("Comment", new mongoose.Schema({ title:String}));
const UserModel = mongoose.model("User", new mongoose.Schema({ name:String}));

The parent Report schema then contains an ObjectId:
    reportedItem: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        refPath: "reportedItemType"
    }})

And a reference to the child model:
    reportedItemType: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ["User","Comment","Post"]
    },

Note that the values for reportedItemType are the model names as passed in the first argument to mongoose.model
The complete runnable example:
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const util = require("util");

const PostModel = mongoose.model("Post", new mongoose.Schema({ title:String}));
const CommentModel = mongoose.model("Comment", new mongoose.Schema({ title:String}));
const UserModel = mongoose.model("User", new mongoose.Schema({ name:String}));

const ReportModel = mongoose.model("Report", new mongoose.Schema({
    reportedItemType: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ["User","Comment","Post"]
    },
    reportedItem: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        refPath: "reportedItemType"
    }})
);

async function main() {
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");

    // create an item of each time, and a report for it
    let post1 = await PostModel.create({title:"first Post"});
    await ReportModel.create({reportedItemType:"Post",reportedItem:post1._id});
    let comment1 = await CommentModel.create({title:"first title"});
    await ReportModel.create({reportedItemType:"Comment",reportedItem:comment1._id});
    let user1 =  await UserModel.create({name:"first user"});
    await ReportModel.create({reportedItemType:"User",reportedItem:user1._id});

    console.log("Report documents:")
    let reports = await ReportModel.find();
    console.log(util.inspect(reports))

    console.log("Populated reports:");
    let result = await ReportModel.find().populate("reportedItem");
    console.log(util.inspect(result));

    process.exit(0);

}

main()

The generated output shows the report documents both before and after calling .populate("reportedItem"):
Report documents:
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('67117353b0fbb3b8471405c9'),
    reportedItemType: 'Post',
    reportedItem: new ObjectId('67117353b0fbb3b8471405c7'),
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('67117353b0fbb3b8471405cd'),
    reportedItemType: 'Comment',
    reportedItem: new ObjectId('67117353b0fbb3b8471405cb'),
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('67117353b0fbb3b8471405d1'),
    reportedItemType: 'User',
    reportedItem: new ObjectId('67117353b0fbb3b8471405cf'),
    __v: 0
  }
]
Populated reports:
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('67117353b0fbb3b8471405c9'),
    reportedItemType: 'Post',
    reportedItem: {
      _id: new ObjectId('67117353b0fbb3b8471405c7'),
      title: 'first Post',
      __v: 0
    },
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('67117353b0fbb3b8471405cd'),
    reportedItemType: 'Comment',
    reportedItem: {
      _id: new ObjectId('67117353b0fbb3b8471405cb'),
      title: 'first title',
      __v: 0
    },
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId('67117353b0fbb3b8471405d1'),
    reportedItemType: 'User',
    reportedItem: {
      _id: new ObjectId('67117353b0fbb3b8471405cf'),
      name: 'first user',
      __v: 0
    },
    __v: 0
  }
]


I don't know,although this answer makes some sense according to documentation, but for me this approach does remove the need to pas the model name with path in populate function, but it is not populating. I might be making some mistake somewhere.
